# ReGex Parsing Underscore Character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this sentence that I need to parse. The senetence is the following bellow:

```
I'm sure _I_ shan't be able!  I shall be a great deal too far off to trouble myself
```

The outcome that I need below is :

```
I'm sure I shan't be able!  I shall be a great deal too far off to trouble myself
```

What would the Exrepssion look like?

The current expression I am using is

```
r'(?!_)\w+'
```

but the outcome I get is:

```
I'm sure I_ shan't be able!  I shall be a great deal too far off to trouble myself
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Do you want to remove `_`? Use `s = s.replace('_', '')`

Comment: That worked fine lol thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this.

```
text = "I'm sure _I_ shan't be able!  I shall be a great deal too far off to trouble myself"

print(text.replace('_',''))
#expected output:
#I'm sure I shan't be able!  I shall be a great deal too far off to trouble myself
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all underscores around a word with:

```
import re

text = "I'm sure _I_ shan't be able! I shall be a great _deal_ too far off to _trouble_ myself"

result = re.sub(r'(_)(\w+)(_)', r'\2', text)

print(result)  # I'm sure I shan't be able! I shall be a great deal too far off to trouble myself
```